# Authentic hadith or supernatural talks?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, source-identification, authenticity, reference-request

Assalaamu a'laykum wa ragmatullahie wabarakaatu!

I have heard from a family member not to wiggle your feet whilst eating. Also that it means `Shaytaan` is busy with you whenever you `play/wiggle` your feet. My question is, is this true? Is there a hadith that can verify this or is this just old people talk?

Shukran!

Comment: Can you please tell me why you edited my question.

Comment: Stack Exchange is a collaborative Q&A site, thus everyone is allowed to [edit (or suggest an edit) a post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to improve it. For example, the additional tags are considerably useful to categorize this question on this site (though the formatting edit was questionable, personally).